# Why isn't my Mercurial pushed files showing up on my remote server?

Tags: mercurial

None of my files pushed are showing up on the remote server, even though it said the push was an success. I'm stumped. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: We'd love to help! If you would only provide some useful information...

Answer (score 2):

I just spent 1 hour wasting my time to find out that I need to do `hg update` on the server. There's a hook that belongs in your hgrc. For me, it was in the `cgi-bin/hgweb.config`

Add:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

Comment: Do you need a current working copy on the server?  Leaving it naked with no working copy whatsoever should work just fine if it's just a push/pull target.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "working copy"? I'm assuming you mean a work copy of mercurial? Well, I use its web to easily look at things with its GUI.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a "bare" repository and a repository that contains a "working copy". Pushing and pulling do not update the working copy of a repository.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your remote repository is not bare, but contains a working copy. Pushing and pulling do not update the working copy. This is what you are seeing.

The bigger question is: why do you need your remote repository to contain a working copy in the first place? This is usually neither desired, nor useful. What is your workflow here? I suspect you may want to read this article on publishing Mercurial repositories carefully: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep